# Jenkins EnvInject before SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I want Jenkins to build the latest tag/branch by setting an env var before the SVN checkout.  I tried using EnvInject but it does not seem to evaluate before the checkout.

I checked `Prepare an environment for run` and set `Properties Content` to

```
SVN_V=`svn ls -v <url> | ...`
echo SVN_V=$SVN_V > build.properties
```

Then I checked `Inject environment variables to the build process` and set `Properties File Path` equal to `build.properties`. I have `Repository url` equal to `<url>/branch/$SVN_V`.

The [EnvInject Page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) has conflicting statements saying "Injects environment variables before or/and after a SCM checkout for a run" is a feature but then further down says its not under Known Limitations.

Running EnvInject 1.92.1 and Jenkins 1.639.  Any help or alternative solution would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you triggering the build? The limitation with EnvInject is that it does not run unless a build is running, so according to their page you cannot use this approach to configure the SVN path for *polling*, but it should work when you actually run a build.

If you are triggering the build manually (or from another build) and it still isn't working (assuming your setup is correct), the easiest way to enforce the property inject order would be to wrap your build in another build, load the props in the wrapper build, and pass the correct tag as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use the [pre-scm-buildstep plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep).

With this plugin, you can use a shell/batch script to collect the information and store them in a properties file.
Next, the InjectEnv plugin will read the properties file and set the variables:

[image]

Next, in the logs, we can see that these 2 steps are executed before the SVN checkout:

[image]

After the SVN checkout, the variable can be used in a build step:

[image]

[image]

Comment: doesn't work.  I tried it with just a string too `echo SVN_V=15.11.1 > build.properties`.  `Location '<svn_url>/branch/$SVN_V' does not exist`

Comment: If you want to use this variable in the Jenkins configuration, please use ${SVN_V}.

Comment: I see what I did, I had the `Inject environment variables` outside of the `Run buildstep before SCM`.  got it working now, thanks!

Comment: actually, it doesn't work for my use case since I'm running an `svn ls` and its failing to authenticate.  I assume the credentials are not available at this point.

Comment: On your Jenkins server, if you open a session with the jenkins user and if you launch a svn command, the credentials will be stored on the machine. Next, the script should work with Jenkins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96981/discussion-between-riotburn-and-bruno-lavit).

Comment: You can even run a groovy Scriptler script. You can access to environment variable with following code : def build = Thread.currentThread().executable; def writer = new FileWriter(build.workspace.toString()+'/variable.properties'); writer.print("MY_VAR=value");

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will not work for SCM polling. I had a similar problem with Perforce plugin + EnvInject ver 1.92. The injected vars are not expanded before SCM polling (even though they are expanded before sources are synced). See also bug [JENKINS-16992](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16992)

My workaround was to install [Hidden Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hidden+Parameter+Plugin) and define the variable as a "Hidden Parameter". I always prefer this trick to EnvInject for simple static Env. variables. It takes less space on config. page and works more reliably